# What does "Dad Joke" mean in the context of the Snowden tweet?

Tags: phrase-usage

Edward Snowden tweeted(https://twitter.com/Snowden/status/691765987566292992) **And you guys say I have dad jokes. ** to the tweet from Neil **"Mars for Ed would be the ultimate asylum, provided the Martians don’t deport him for being an illegal alien"**

Is Edward disappointed by the joke made by Neil? Please explain.

Comment: Bad, silly puns, mostly. The kind of jokes (mostly silly puns) your dad would tell you when you were a kid, and no one would laugh but him. But he would laugh a lot. "*Dad! I'm hungry.*" / "*Hello Hungry, nice to meet you, I'm Dad!*". In this particular case, it's a pun on the dual meaning of *alien*: human being from another country vs visitor from another planet, not even the same species.

Answer (score 4):

It is a recent expression that refers to lame, poor jokes no one would find funny:

[Dad joke](http://www.yourdictionary.com/da):

> - (slang) A lame, embarassing or unfunny joke told by someone's father.

(Yourdictionary.com)

[Dad Jokes](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/dad-jokes):

> - is a pejorative label typically used to describe a variety of failed attempts at humor involving corny puns, anti-jokes or predictable punchlines, some of the prime examples being Trolldad, Bad Joke Eel and Lame Pun Coon.

Origin

> - While the exact origin of the term “dad joke” is unknown, the earliest known use of the term online was posted in a thread by B3ta Forums member rob on December 10th, 2003, which asked other members to submit “lame jokes” made by their fathers. In the first 48 hours, the thread received 15 pages worth of replies.

(knowyourmeme.com)

Comment: I'd hesitate to call them lame or unfunny. They're generally the same as bad puns – so incredibly dumb that you laugh.